How to fix "cannot access Input/Output error" (SOLVED)
everyone!
My wife was using a laptop running ZorinOS, but that machine broke.
I took the HD and plugged it in an external case, and tried to access the files from my machine (Ubuntu 22.04). I can see the /home/mywife folder/directory but when I try to open it, the system returns the follow error message:

cannot access Input/output error


Does this mean that the HD is corrupted?
If not, there is a way to access the files there?

Obs: we know my wife machine's password.
Thank you for any help!

Firstly have you checked the drive's health?  ie. using the SMART capabilities of the drive (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)  as its where I'd start... If the drive is failing, I'd NOT try and do anything to fix issues, but save any remaining life left in restoring files starting with most important first... but plan this before you start!   Rather than OS (Zorin is off-topic, but if using Ubuntu to recover files you're on-topic here) file-system details are what matter and you gave none... You mention your release, but again no specifics (Server? Desktop? etc)

Questions: is the drive a platter(mechanical) or ssd?  You said the other machine broke. Was the hard drive the issue or did it break for other reasons?  Was the original drive encrypted.  It is all too easy to click yes to the suggestion to encrypt.
There are a few possibilities.  Have you tried to look into it as root.  I know this is not recommended but you could install Thunar and then from command line sudo thunar.  That will give you more "power" in case its locked.  Could also be some incompatibility between the case and the drive.  Try a usb 2 port.

Thank you, @guiverc and @walttheboss for your kind answers to my request for help.

I plugged the HDD (as @walttheboss witty made me notice, I had not informed that it is a HDD) again on the Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 (here you have it, @guiverc. Thank you again), and ran dmesg. I can't paste the results here because me, in my stupidity, forget to save it. But I can remember that there was a message of section error.

So, I turn back the HDD on the old machine (@guiverc, yes, the same machine that was running Zorin OS - I mentioned it before in a naïve belief that it would be sufficient to make known that the file system was ext4 - again, a naivety). I tried to load Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 from a flashdrive (live section) but yet could not access the files. But, this time, in the loading screen of Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 an error appeared:



Blockquotefsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda2: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.


/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
(i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda6 requires a manual fsck
Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs) _

So, I searched for a diagnostic and found a simple solution here: fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY
I hope it could help anyone with the same/similar problem.

fsck /dev/sda6

fixed the issue and I could access the HDD again. My wife is happy and my marriage is safe again.
Thank you all. Nothing is like the community.
